# Question about contextual embeddings?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

How do BERT and RoBERTa generate contextual embeddings? The articles I've read keep saying that transformer encoders work bidirectionally. Because of self-attention, they can look at every token, unlike RNN/LSTM, which can only process the previous hidden state. Is it true ? I'm not sure how BERT and RoBERTa accomplish that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Transformer is Bidirectional - Machine Learning](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47397/how-transformer-is-bidirectional-machine-learning)

Comment: I'm actually looking for the mathematical explanation instead of just reading claims that it's bidirectional, attends to every token, and produces contextual embeddings, etc. It would be helpful if I could understand the entire process from input to output of BERT or RoBERTa that creates contextual embeddings

Comment: You can find the mathematical explanations in the [original Transformers article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) together with the [BERT article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805). For a friendlier version you can check [the Illustrated BERT blog post](https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-bert/).

Answer (score 0):

Start with a sequence of embeddings.

In the standard attention computation, each embedding in the sequence attends to every other embedding in the sequence. This can be considered "bidirectional" as a given embedding is attending every other embedding, considering the full sequence.

Masked language models (MLMs) like BERT use this form of attention.